# Moving multiple WSP solutions in to one WSP solution

Tags: solution-deployment

We have tree solutions that we are deploying by retract deploy approach. One problem is that two of the solutions deploys as global solutions, on is web application scoped. This recycles all the web applications on the server, this is a problem as there are other solutions affected by an deploy. I'm thinking about making a deployment solution that combines all the solution in on wsp package. That will be web application scoped and therefor only recycles the web application that it is deployed to.

I have tested to retract tree solutions and deploy as on in my environment and i worked nicely, but I'm wondering if this can be an issue in a farm with several servers. Is it safe to retract the tree old solutions the deploy them as one solution? (they are only needed in one web application).